# Background Image Doesn't Show On Route Change

Tags: ionic4, stenciljs

I have noticed something weird in my ionic app and have not been able to find a solution to it.

This is my css:

```
ion-content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  --background: url(/assets/img/banners/bus.jpg) fixed 0 0/cover !important;
  background: url(/assets/img/banners/bus.jpg) fixed 0 0/cover !important;
  min-height: 800px;
}
```

This is my jsx:

```
render() {
    return [
        <ion-content>
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col class="text">
                        <ion-text color="light">
                            <h1 class="font-light animated slideInLeft">
                                BUS <strong class="font-black">SCHEDULES</strong>
                                <br /><small><ion-text id="company"></ion-text> • <ion-text id="route"></ion-text> • <ion-text id="date"></ion-text></small>
                            </h1>
                        </ion-text>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row class="schedules">

                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </ion-content>
    ]
}
```

When I navigate to this page the background image does not load: 
[image]

However when I refresh the page the image loads.
So just to be clear, when I navigate to the page in my app background image does not show however when I refresh page it shows.

I am not using angular or any other framework.

Comment: Can you please share you stencil.config file?

Comment: It may be a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752193/stenciljs-route-to-new-content-and-cannot-change-background