# Stenciljs: route to new content and cannot change background

Tags: ionic4, stenciljs

I'm currently creating my first PWA with Stencil, PWA Toolkit and Ionic 4. 
I can not explain myself a behavior when switching from one page (ion-content) to another page.
Here the situation:

CSS 1st page (app-home):

```
ion-content {
         --background: pink;
            }
```

CSS 2nd page (app-data):

```
ion-content {
         --background: white;
}
```

With the statement:

```
this.router.push ('/data', 'forward');
```

the app changes from page 1 to page 2. But the background remains pink and does not change as expected to white.
When I refresh the url “/data” the background becomes white. When I then return to the first page the background 
remains white.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It works this way because there are no css scoping in Stencil by default so rule for the for `ion-content` selector is applied twice in your page.

You need to prepend each style with a component selector to correctly scope them.

For example:

```
app-home ion-content {
  --background: pink;
}
```

Read more about styling in Stencil [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/styling)

Comment: I can confirm this, had the same issue, resolved it this way.